# How te force chrome to keep extension alive while clicking on page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I clicking on page extension popup automaticly disappear.

I during development of my first chrome-extension, with Vue. I need to keep pop up alivie when sometime clicking anything on the page, but by default pop up closing on page click. How to force pop up to keep up all the time?

I expect to keep it up, by changing some code in extension code

Comment: You can't force it in Chrome during normal operation. But you can open devtools of the popup itself by right-clicking inside so the popup will stay open while devtools is open.

Comment: I know it, but I need some way to keep it's alivie
@wOxxOm

Comment: There's no other way.